# What does char(*)[int] mean in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm reading [this article on SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and I find this fun pair of functions:

```
template<int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template<int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected  when I is odd
}
```

This works well (g++-4.9), but I don't really understand the type of the parameter  (the `char(*)[int]` -part.). Anyone else who does?

Comment: Technically, it's a pointer to an array of zero or one character.

Comment: In this case it doesn't really matter, as it's only used for template resolution.

In more modern C++, you could simply add the check to the template list and use `enable_if`.

Comment: That looks like `char(*)[bool]` to me

Comment: Yes @Hurkyl, in the example it's a bool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`char(*)[I % 2 == 0]` means *pointer to array of `char` with dimension `I % 2 == 0`*.  It is illegal to have a pointer to array of dimension `0`, and SFINAE says that this causes the template not to be considered (as opposed to a compilation error occurring).

Comment: Accepted, since you also explained how the type pertains to the context in which it's used.

Answer (score 6):

`char(*)[I % 2 == 1]` is the type of a pointer to array of `I % 2 == 1` `char`s. You can use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to solve such riddles. See also the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).